# Show the following is correct using big O and big Omega

Tags: big-o

I'm a little confused on how to go about solving this problem

```
Show that the following is correct:
5n^2 - 6n = Theta(n^2)
```

I understand that I'm supposed to set up an inequality but not sure where to go from there

Edit: Made a typo but its fixed now

Comment: 5n^2 - 6n <= cn^2 but I don't know what to solve for or what to prove

Answer (score 0):

As hints, for any n, you can see that

> 5n<sup>2</sup> - 6n ≤ 5n

Also, for n ≥ 6, notice that

> 5n<sup>2</sup> - 6n ≥ 5n<sup>2</sup> - n<sup>2</sup>

See if you can use these observations, plus the formal definition of big-O notation, to prove that 5n<sup>2</sup> - 6n = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).

Hope this helps!